# Regular expression extracting a string from url

Tags: java, regex

What I am trying is to extract my account id from a url for other validations.
see my URL samples.

```
http://localhost:8024/accounts/u8m21ercgelj/
http://localhost:8024/accounts/u8m21ercgelj
http://localhost:8024/accounts/u8m21ercgelj/users?
```

What I required is to extract u8m21ercgelj from the url. I tried it with below code but it fails for the cases like   `http://localhost:8024/accounts/u8m21ercgelj` 
i.e with out a / at the end.

```
public  String extractAccountIdFromURL(String url) {
        String accountId = null;
        if ( url.contains("accounts")) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[accounts]/(.*?)/");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
            while (matcher.find()) {

                accountId = matcher.group(1);
            }
        }
        return accountId;
    }
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `[accounts]` doesn't try to find `accounts` word, but one character which is either `a`, `c` (repetition of character doesn't change anything), `o`, `u`, `n`, `t` or `s` because `[...]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). So get rid of those `[` and `]` and replace them with `/` since you most likely don't want to accept cases like `/specialaccounts/` but only `/accounts/`.
2. It looks like you just want to find next non-/ section after `/accounts/`. In that case you can just use `/accounts/([^/]+)`
3. If you are sure that there will be only one `/accounts/` section in URL you can (and for more readable code should) change your `while` to `if` or even conditional operator. Also there is no need for `contains("/accounts/")` since it just adds additional traversing over entire string which can be done in `find()`.
4. It doesn't look like your method is using any data held by your class (any fields) so it could be static.

Demo:

```
//we should resuse once compiled regex, there is no point in compiling it many times
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/accounts/([^/]+)");
public static String extractAccountIdFromURL(String url) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
}

public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) throws Exception {
    String examples = 
            "http://localhost:8024/accounts/u8m21ercgelj/\r\n" + 
            "http://localhost:8024/accounts/u8m21ercgelj\r\n" + 
            "http://localhost:8024/accounts/u8m21ercgelj/users?";
    for (String url : examples.split("\\R")){// split on line separator like `\r\n`
        System.out.println(extractAccountIdFromURL(url));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
u8m21ercgelj
u8m21ercgelj
u8m21ercgelj
```

Comment: @ANP I am wondering why you uses `while` instead of `if`. Are you assuming that there can be more than one `/accounts/` in URL? If not then to not confuse people who will maintain this code you should change it to `if`. But if url can have many `/accounts/` then posted solution may fail for cases like `/accounts/accounts/foo` (I could try to correct it, so let me know if correction is needed).

Comment: Good point, I didn't even look at the `[accounts]` part of it in my answer. +1 for this answer.

Comment: HI All, Only one account will be there in my URL. I will correct the snippet .Thank you All

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is written as such that it is expecting to receive a trailing slash - that's what the slash after the `(.*?)` means.

You should change this so that it can accept either the trailing slash, or the end of the string. `(/|$)` should work in this case, meaning your regex would be `[accounts]/(.*?)(/|$)`